# Emmet preferences.json in Visual Studio Code to include Stylus (CSS preprocessor)

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, stylus, emmet

The emmet snippets that are included by default in Visual Studio Code work fine in CSS, HTML, LESS, SASS files. However I prefer using Stylus for my CSS coding.

These snippets don't seem to work in VS Code. I have installed the Stylus plugin, but this didn't help. Then I've found in the documentation of Emmet that I can change the preferences.json to add a syntax:

```
css.syntaxes
List of syntaxes that should be treated as CSS dialects.
css, less, sass, scss, stylus, styl
```

I cannot find where VS Code stores the emmet settings however, so I cannot check if this helps my problem.

So my question is, where can I change the preferences.json in VS Code? Even more helpful would be, how can I get the Stylus snippets of Emmet to work (so it gives me 'position absolute' when I type 'posa'-TAB for example)?

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed this on the VS Code GitHub repo as an issue and they've added Stylus as a CSS alias.

Still they haven't told me where I could find this file. The change was made in a code file.

The issue: [The issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6062)

So this solved my problem.